# How do i delete text line from a txt file? ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, builder

Good morning! So here is basic code, which i get from the "Mobile Development with Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 and Flash Builder 4.5" tutorial. Pretty much basic code, but those bastards didnt gave any information about DELETE function. THis is my first time application for this, so help is needed!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           height="494" creationComplete="readFile()"> 
<fx:Script> 
<![CDATA[ 


import mx.collections.ArrayCollection; 
[Bindable] public var todo_items:ArrayCollection;     
private function readFile():void 
{ 
    var todoFile:File =File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("todo.txt"); 

    if (todoFile.exists) 
    { 
        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
        fs.open(todoFile, FileMode.READ); 
        var result:String = fs.readUTFBytes(fs.bytesAvailable); 
        var items:Array = result.split("\n"); 
        items.pop(); 
        todo_items = new ArrayCollection(items); 
        fs.close(); 
    } 
    else { trace("Aplication cant find the file"); 
    } 
 } 
    private function writeFile():void 
    { 
        var todoFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("todo.txt"); 


            var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
            fs.open(todoFile, FileMode.APPEND); 


            fs.writeUTFBytes(task_txt.text + "\n"); 


            fs.close(); 
            readFile(); 
    } 
    private function deleteFile():void 
    { 
        //????????????? HEEEEELP         !!!!!!!!!! 
    } 

]]> 
</fx:Script> 


<s:List id="todo_list" left="10" right="10" top="146" bottom="87"       dataProvider="{todo_items}"/> 
<s:Button left="11" right="10" top="69" height="65" label="Save task" click="writeFile()" 
          enabled="{task_txt.text.length > 0}"/> 
<s:TextInput id="task_txt" left="10" right="10" top="10" height="51" prompt="Specify a task"/> 
<s:Button left="10" right="10" bottom="14" label="Delete" 
          click="todo_items.removeItemAt(todo_list.selectedIndex); deleteFile()" 
                        enabled="{todo_list.selectedIndex != -1}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is

1. read in all of the data from the file, just like readFile is doing.
2. delete from that data whatever lines you want to delete.
3. write the data back to the file - like writeFile is doing - in `FileMode.WRITE` mode, as you want it to overwrite, not append.

If you can't quite figure this out and need code instead of a guide, feel free to comment on here and I'll give you more than just pointers.

---

The code in readFile (all of it) reads in the data from the file into an ArrayCollection called `todo_items`.

If you want to remove an item from the file, you want to remove it from that ArrayCollection (something like `todo_items.removeItemAt(index)`).

Now, you have an ArrayCollection containing the data you want to be in the file. At this point, you need to imitate what writeFile() is doing, but with FileMode.WRITE, and you want to write out every item in your list, instead of the one item in the textbox you want to add.

```
private function deleteFile():void 
{ 
    var todoFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("todo.txt"); 


        var fs:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
        fs.open(todoFile, FileMode.WRITE); 

        for(var item:String in todo_items)
        {
            fs.writeUTFBytes(item + "\n")
        }

        fs.close(); 
        readFile(); 
}
```

On a somewhat related note - I don't think 'deleteFile' is a good name for what you are doing here. You might want a `deleteItem()` method that deletes the selected item, and then a `saveFile()` method that contains the code above.

Comment: The problems is that this is my first step at this, and i actually have no idea what code lines should i use, so it would be really helpful if you give me needed pieces of code. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Take a look, I've given you a little more guidance.

Comment: Your solution works, but it gives me for some reason numbers instead of Text lines. For example when i add "Feed dog, feed cat, feed fish, feed bird" and then Delete the 3d item in the result it gives me "0, 1, 2". Have no clue why

Comment: Hmm. It's hard to say why that would happen, unless you're printing out the index instead of the item. Would have to see more code to help debug that.

Comment: Have found the problem - it must be fs.writeUTFBytes(todo_items[item] + "\n") instead of fs.writeUTFBytes(item + "\n")

Answer (score -1):

I presume the deleteFile method is intended to delete the file? If so, Adobe's Reference documents the [File class and deletion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#deleteFile%28%29) this is normally a good place to start when exploring classes.

```
private function deleteFile():void 
{ 
       var todoFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("todo.txt"); 
       todoFile.deleteFile()
}
```